# Cannot add class to the elements created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I'd like to create basic remove and delete with jquery.
But I have a problem with jquery append, why I cannot addClass active on new <li> when I click append.

when I click <li> it will be adding class active on <li>, and then I want to remove <li> has class active

Can anyone help me why this is happen

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var list=$('ul.appendWrap > li').length;
  
  $('.btn_append').click(function(){
      $('ul.appendWrap').append('<li>new</li>');   
  });
  
  $('.btn_remove').click(function(){
    $('li.active').remove();
  });
  
  $("ul.appendWrap li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
  
});
```

```css
li, a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="appendWrap">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn_append">append</a>
<a class="btn_remove">remove</a>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `event` delegation for elements which were added `dynamically`.

You should bind `click` event handler using `.on()` method.

**Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.**

Read more about `event delegation` [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var list=$('ul.appendWrap > li').length;
  
  $('.btn_append').click(function(){
      $('ul.appendWrap').append('<li>new</li>');   
  });
  
  $('.btn_remove').click(function(){
    $('li.active').remove();
  });
  
  $(document).on("click","ul.appendWrap li",function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
  
});
```

```css
li, a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="appendWrap">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn_append">append</a>
<a class="btn_remove">remove</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the following:

```
$("ul.appendWrap li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

To

```
$(document).on('click',"ul.appendWrap li",function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

because **$("ul.appendWrap li").click(function(){});** works for static html and you are adding html dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

If your page was dynamically creating elements you would bind the event to a parent which already exists, often document.

```
$(document).on('click',"ul.appendWrap li",function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The elements that you are appending do not exist in  defined click-function. To fix it you may use delegate() method from jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var list=$('ul.appendWrap > li').length;

  $('.btn_append').click(function(){
      $('ul.appendWrap').append('<li>new</li>');   
  });

  $('.btn_remove').click(function(){
    $('li.active').remove();
  });



  $("ul.appendWrap").delegate('li','click',function() {
     $(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
li, a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="appendWrap">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<a class="btn_append">append</a>
<a class="btn_remove">remove</a>
```